# Google Play Protect

Tags: android, google-play

With Android 8 (Oreo), Google is promoting this feature

- Google Play Protect:
  Working to keep your device and data safe from misbehaving apps by **scanning over 50 billion apps per day**, even the ones you haven't installed yet!

My question is: how do they scan 50b apps/day if Google Play store doesn't even have that many apps? 
A quick look at this shows there is roughly 3.5 million apps in their store as of late 2017
https://www.statista.com/statistics/266210/number-of-available-applications-in-the-google-play-store/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, I think that includes apps already installed on people's phones. I believe there is 2+ billion Android users out there